# Write a List of Dictionaries to the same row in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have the following list of dictionaries which I have tried to create into a dataframe, I have managed to get all the 'Header' values into a df but I can't workout how to get 'Values', I am trying to get bother Header and Values in the same row.

> new_inner = [{'Header': {'TimeserieId': '108', 'ObjectID': 'SummeSLPVerbrauchDayAhead', 'Unit': 'kWh', 'Granularity': 'DAY', 'Name': 'SLP consumption forecasts day ahead', 'LastUpdate': '2017-12-30T11:15:00.000Z'}, 'Values': {'Value': {'FromUTC': '2017-12-31T05:00:00.000Z', 'UntilUTC': '2018-01-01T05:00:00.000Z', 'TSO-Value': '100947866.161'}}}, {'Header': {'TimeserieId': '109', 'ObjectID': 'SummeSLPVerbrauchIntraDay', 'Unit': 'kWh', 'Granularity': 'DAY', 'Name': 'SLP consumption forecasts intraday', 'LastUpdate': '2017-12-31T23:15:00.000Z'}, 'Values': {'Value': {'FromUTC': '2017-12-31T05:00:00.000Z', 'UntilUTC': '2018-01-01T05:00:00.000Z', 'TSO-Value': '100359943.649'}}}, {'Header': {'TimeserieId': '2156', 'ObjectID': 'SummeSLPVerbrauchTirolIntraDay', 'Unit': 'kWh', 'Granularity': 'DAY', 'Name': 'SLP consumption forecasts intraday Tyrol', 'LastUpdate': '2019-12-30T15:44:14.267Z'}, 'Values': None}, {'Header': {'TimeserieId': '2157', 'ObjectID': 'SummeSLPVerbrauchTirolDayAhead', 'Unit': 'kWh', 'Granularity': 'DAY', 'Name': 'SLP consumption forecasts day ahead Tyrol', 'LastUpdate': '2019-12-30T15:44:14.269Z'}, 'Values': None}, {'Header': {'TimeserieId': '2158', 'ObjectID': 'SummeSLPVerbrauchVorarlbergIntraDay', 'Unit': 'kWh', 'Granularity': 'DAY', 'Name': 'SLP consumption forecasts intraday VBG', 'LastUpdate': '2019-12-30T15:44:14.273Z'}, 'Values': None}, {'Header': {'TimeserieId': '2159', 'ObjectID': 'SummeSLPVerbrauchVorarlbergDayAhead', 'Unit': 'kWh', 'Granularity': 'DAY', 'Name': 'SLP consumption forecasts day ahead VBG', 'LastUpdate': '2019-12-30T15:44:14.294Z'}, 'Values': None}]

Current code:

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame([i['Header'] for i in new_inner])
```

However if I try and do:

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame([i['Values'] for i in new_inner])
```

I get the following error

> 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'keys'

My two questions are why does it not find the Values Dictionary and how would I get the Header and Values dictionaries into the same row in a dataframe?

I am looking for the output to look like:
[DataFrame Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43QuZ.png)

Comment: Key values is sometines None, and if not if has an inner dict, how do you expect it to be parsed ?

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO ! You should minify your exemple, that will help people to answer your question and help yourself to debug. Furthermore, I highly suspect `i['Values']` being `None` as shown on the last line of your json.

Comment: how you expect the output??

Comment: What do you mean by minify my example?  Make it smaller?  There are some values in the Values dictionary but not for all of them.

Comment: @hey_arnold you can find documentation about [mre here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Do not forget to include your expected output for a small input

Comment: I have now included an output. sorry for not including earlier

Comment: You may now think about accepting an answer or comment one to get details ;) to reward those who spent time for you ;)

Comment: Sorry azro, I didn't know I needed to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest to prepare the data first, then convert to a `Dataframe`

- fo each `dict` flatten keys `Header` + `Values` to a single dict
- for key `Values` check if is `None` to return a default dict value, or the inner key `Value`

```
values = [{'Header': {...}}] # initial data

def getValueOrDefault(v):
    if v is None:
        return {'FromUTC': None, 'UntilUTC': None, 'TSO-Value': None}
    return v['Value']

values = [{**value['Header'], **getValueOrDefault(value['Values'])} for value in values]
# values is now [{'TimeserieId': '108', ...}, {}, {}, ...]

df3 = pd.DataFrame(values)
print(df3)
```

---

*Detailf of data preparation: example for the first value*

- `{**first['Header']}` flat all the key/values from `Header` value, to remove this level of data
- `{**value['Header'], **value['Values']}` puts all key/values from key `Header`  and key `Values` together **but** as you have some `None` you may apply a verification,

  - if `None` get a default dict with the good keys
  - if not `None` retrieve the khe inner `Value` key

```
first = values[0]
print(first) # {'Header': {'TimeserieId': '108', 'ObjectID': 'SummeSLPVerbrauchDayAhead', 'Unit': 'kWh', 'Granularity': 'DAY', 'Name': 'SLP consumption forecasts day ahead', 'LastUpdate': '2017-12-30T11:15:00.000Z'}, 'Values': {'Value': {'FromUTC': '2017-12-31T05:00:00.000Z', 'UntilUTC': '2018-01-01T05:00:00.000Z', 'TSO-Value': '100947866.161'}}}
print({**first['Header']}) # {'TimeserieId': '108', 'ObjectID': 'SummeSLPVerbrauchDayAhead', 'Unit': 'kWh', 'Granularity': 'DAY', 'Name': 'SLP consumption forecasts day ahead', 'LastUpdate': '2017-12-30T11:15:00.000Z'}
print({**first['Values']}) # {'Value': {'FromUTC': '2017-12-31T05:00:00.000Z', 'UntilUTC': '2018-01-01T05:00:00.000Z', 'TSO-Value': '100947866.161'}}
print({**getValueOrDefault(first['Values'])}) # {'FromUTC': '2017-12-31T05:00:00.000Z', 'UntilUTC': '2018-01-01T05:00:00.000Z', 'TSO-Value': '100947866.161'}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, please could you explain how this line of code works:

Comment: values = [{**value['Header'], **getValueOrDefault(value['Values'])} for value in values]

Comment: @hey_arnold i've add some details